# Using DISM on a remote host

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, dism

I'm trying to use a dism command to enable a few windows features on several different machines.

Here is an example:

```
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:MSMQ-Container
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:MSMQ-Server
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:MSMQ-Triggers
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:MSMQ-ADIntegration
```

But I don't want to install them on the current machine. Is there a way to push this command to a remote host using the Hostname?

I don't know if there is another option for reading and enabling features on other machines, but I'm trying to make it so a single machine with admin access can configure the whole environment of machines without going in to each one to run a command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use psexec, like this:

```
psexec.exe \\NETBIOS_NAME DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All /LimitAccess /Source:path_to_cource
```